# What is the time complexity for looking up an item in a Perl hash?

Tags: perl, hash

Suppose I have a file with n words. As I read each word in the file, I will store it in hash (in Perl). When I go back and look up for the word in the hash, what is the time complexity of looking up a string(word) in a hash?

For example:

```
my %seen = ();
@arr=("one","two","three");
foreach $item (@arr){
    if($seen{$item}) {//do something}
}
```

In this program, I am looking up for an item in the hash. What is time complexity of looking up for a string in a hash?

Also, could any elaborate on how hash is implemented in Perl? (internally something happens in hash? or is it just an associative array)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl, time efficient hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029670/perl-time-efficient-hash)

Answer (score 11):

Perl hashes provide constant-time lookups. They are implemented as true hash tables (with automatic retuning as necessary), not associative arrays.

Comment: Is this irrespective of whatever the key is? Key can be a string also..right?

Comment: @sekhar, the key can _only_ be a string.  Numbers and references get converted to strings when used as hash keys.

Comment: Perl hashes _are_ associative arrays.  An [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) is an abstract data type; hash tables are one way to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see how Perl implements hashes, work your way through the source in *hv.c* and *hv.h*. If you want just the overview, you might try [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html). However, as friedo says, the time to look up any key is the same time to look up any other key. It's a real hash.

You might also want to see Jon Bentley's essays on hashes in *Programming Pearls* (not a Perl book).