# What do you get if you evaluate a hash in scalar context?

Tags: perl

Consider the following snippet:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %a = ( a => 1,
          b => 2,
          c => 'cucu',
          d => undef,
          r => 1,
          br => 2,
          cr => 'cucu',
          dr => '321312321',

        );

my $c = %a;

print $c;
```

The result of this is `5/8` and I don't understand what this represents. I read somewhere that a number from this *fraction* looking result might represent the number of buckets from the hash, but clearly this is not the case.

Does anyone knows how a perl hash is evaluated in scalar context?

**Edit**

I added a few other hashes to print:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.010;


my %a = ( a => 1,
          b => 2,
          c => 'cucu',
          d => undef,
          r => 1,
          br => 2,
          cr => 'cucu',
          dr => '321312321',

        );

my $c = %a;

say $c; # 5/8


%a = ( a => 1,
       b => 21,
       c => 'cucu',
       br => 2,
       cr => 'cucu',
       dr => '321312321',

      );

 $c = %a;

say $c; # 4/8

%a = ( a => 1,
       b => 2,
       c => 'cucu',
       d => undef,
       r => 1,
       br => 2,
       cr => 'cucu',
       dr => '321312321',
       drr => '32131232122',
      );

 $c = %a;

say $c; #6/8
```

So, you call a 'tuple' like `a => 1` a bucket in the hash? in that case, why is the last hash still having 8 as a denominator when it has 9 'tuples' ?

Thank you all for your responses until now :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is 4/16 in hashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723172/what-is-4-16-in-hashes)

Comment: Did you already know that [*`Boolean context is just a special kind of scalar context`*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42927178/2932052)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[*The OP is asking about the format of the string returned by a hash in scalar context before Perl 5.26. Since Perl 5.26, a hash in scalar context no longer returns a string in this format, returning the number of elements in the hash instead. If you need the value discussed here, you can use [Hash::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Util)'s `bucket_ratio()`.*]

A hash is an array of linked lists. A hashing function converts the key into a number which is used as the index of the array element ("bucket") into which to store the value. The linked list handles the case where more than one key hashes to the same index ("collision").

The denominator of the fraction is the total number of buckets.

The numerator of the fraction is the number of buckets which has one or more elements.

For hashes with the same number of elements, the higher the number, the better.  The one that returns 6/8 has fewer collisions than the one that returns 4/8.

Comment: This doesn't apply to Perl 5.25 and newer. See my answer for the new behavior.

Comment: @Daniel Böhmer, Adjusted.

Answer (score 7):

From [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash
>   is empty.  If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more
>   precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of
>   used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a
>   slash.

In your case, you have five values (`1`,`2`,`''cucu'`,`undef`, and `'321312321'`) that have been mapped to by eight keys (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`r`,`br`,`cr`, and `dr`).

Comment: Then again, it's unclear that this pattern holds in general: when I run  `my %h=("a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3);my $a=%h;print "$a\n";`, I get an output of `3/8`.  =/

Comment: The fact that he happens to have 5 distinct values is just a coincidence.  You can give each key a different value, and Perl will still report 5/8.  The bucket usage depends only on the keys in the hash.

Comment: @Jack: The interpretation is wrong. The more buckets are used the better. A bucket in a typical hash table contains a key (which is a hash of the user supplied key) and a list of values which contain all values that are mapped by the same key (the different keys are said to collide). The longer the list grows the longer access times get.

Comment: @Jack: It's `3/8` because the three keys use three buckets and eight total buckets is the smallest number that perl will allocate for a hash.

Comment: @Everyone:  My apologies about the incorrect reason why the hash in scalar context evaluated to `3/8`.  Thank you for pointing me in the direction of figuring out what a bucket in a hash table actually is.

Comment: @JackManey:  You can edit your answer to correct the mistake.  If you do I will upvote your answer because unlike the accepted answer you actually cite the documentation.

Comment: Aside from the quoted part, this answer is very wrong. The numerator does not refer to the number of values, and the denominator does not refer to the number of keys.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour has changed since Perl 5.25. See [perldata for Perl 5.26](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.26.0/perldata.html#Scalar-values):

> Prior to Perl 5.25 the value returned was a string consisting of the
>   number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by
>   a slash. This is pretty much useful only to find out whether Perl's
>   internal hashing algorithm is performing poorly on your data set. For
>   example, you stick 10,000 things in a hash, but evaluating `%HASH` in
>   scalar context reveals `1/16`, which means only one out of sixteen
>   buckets has been touched, and presumably contains all 10,000 of your
>   items. This isn't supposed to happen.
>
> As of Perl 5.25 the return was changed to be the count of keys in the
>   hash. If you need access to the old behavior you can use
>   `Hash::Util::bucket_ratio()` instead.

Comment: The question was specifically about the meaning of the string returned prior to 5.26, not about what hashes return in general. I'll include a note in my answer that that hashes no longer returns the string the OP asked about.

Comment: You're right. Job done very carefully! Still the question title reads *What do you get if you evaluate a hash in scalar context?*. So I'll leave this here because it answers the question in the title what is exactly why I came here in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The number of used buckets starts out to be approximately the number of keys; allocated buckets is consistently the lowest power of 2 > the number of keys.  5 keys will return 5/8.  Larger numbers of unique keys grow slower, such that a hash %h that is just the list (1..128), with 64 key/value pairs, somehow gets a scalar value of 50/128.

However, once the hash has allocated its buckets, they will remain allocated even if you shrink the hash.  I just made a hash %h with 9 pairs, thus 9/16 scalar; then when I reassigned %h to have just one pair, its scalar value was 1/16.

This actually makes sense in that it lets you test the hash's size, like a scalar of a simple array does.

Comment: It depends on the keys you provide. Some keys may collide which leads to only 50 buckets being used instead of 64 in your particular example. You could generate keys that fill 64 buckets or only one (which would be bad for performance).

Answer (score 1):

To focus too much on this *fractional pattern* (as an indicator for internal details of the hash), can be confusing. There is an aspect of the "scalar value" of a hash that is important for potentially every Perl program and that is, if it is considered **true** in ***Boolean context***, see an example:

```
if (%h) {
    print "Entries in hash:\n";
    for my $k (sort keys %h) {
        print "$k: $h{$k}\n";
    }
}
```

In [*perldoc perldata*, section *Scalar-values*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values), you can read that

> [...] The Boolean context is just a special kind of scalar context where no conversion to a string or a number is ever performed.

and, some paragraphs later,

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash
>   is empty.  If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true [...]