# Hash printing number of elements

Tags: perl

I have a code as below

```
@array = qw(Sam London George Washington Luke Shanghai);
my %where = @array;
my @d = keys %where;
my @c = values %where;

print "4. keys - @d values - @c \n";
```

I am getting

```
4. keys - George Luke Sam values - Washington Shanghai London
```

I should be getting 4. keys - Sam George Luke values - London Washington Shanghai

Then I have

```
my ($a) = %where;
my $b = %where;
my $c = $b + 1;
print "6. $a $b $c \n"
```

Why am I getting

```
6. George 2/8 3
```

So, firstly why am I getting incorrect order when I change array to hash.
Secondly, how do I get 2/8 and 3. Instead I am expecting 6 and 7, since there are 6 elements in the hash (3 hash and 3 keys).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hash does not guarantee to store keys and values in any particular order. That's why `@d` and `@c` are in an order you don't expect them to be.

`2/8` is what the hash is evaluated to in scalar context. This is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7428025/4295017. [The following reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7427414/4295017) gives a relevant cite from `perldata`.

The `2/8` value is stored in `$b` as string. When evaluated in integer context (imposed by `$b + 1` operation) this string value gets converted to `2`. That's why `$c` is `3`.

Answer (score 2):

First, hashes have no order to rely on, to say the least. From [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)

> Hash entries are returned in an apparently random order. The actual random order is specific to a given hash; the exact same series of operations on two hashes may result in a different order for each hash.   [ ... ]

This is done on purpose, see the [reason in perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks). You can [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) them to print or assign though.

The other problem is due to using a hash in the scalar context. From [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a slash.

The rest of that documentation passage explains it further.

If you want the number of pairs assign `keys %h` to a scalar, or use [scalar](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) on it.