# Perl: can I skip the intermediate hash variable in this case?

Tags: perl, hashmap

At the moment, I use something like this:

```
my %tmpHash = routineReturningHash();
my $value = $tmpHash{'someKey'};
```

The only thing I need is `$value`, I do not need `%tmpHash` itself. So I am curious to know if there is a way to avoid declaring `%tmpHash`.

I tried

```
my $value = ${routineReturningHash()}{'someKey'};
```

but it doesn't work and outputs a strange error: "`Can't use string ("1/256") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use`".

Any ideas how it could be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a hashref out of the returned list, which you can then dereference

```
my $value = { routineReturningHash() }->{somekey};
```

---

In what you tried, the `${ ... }` imposes the scalar context inside. [From perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) (my emphasis)

> **2.**  
>   Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a BLOCK **returning a reference** of the correct type.

In the scalar context the hash is evaluated to a string with fraction [involving buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7428025/4653379); not a hashref.

---

**Update**   I take it that there are design reasons for returning a hash as a flat list. If that isn't the case, then the clear solution is to just return a hashref from the sub.

That also saves a data copy: When you return a hash the scalars (keys and values) need be copied, to provide a list to the caller; when you return a reference only that one scalar is returned.

As for performance benefits ... if you can see a difference, you either have massive hashes which should be handled by reference anyway, or too many function calls what may need refactoring.

To return by reference you can

- form and work with a hash in the sub and then `return \%hash;`
- form a hashref directly `return { key => 'value', ... };`
- If you have a big hash to work with, pass its reference and work with that

  ```
  sub work_by_ref {    
      my ($hr) = @_;
      $hr->{key} = 'value';
      return 1;
  }

  my %hash;
  work_by_ref(\%hash);
  say "$_ => $hash{$_}" for sort keys %hash;
  ```

  Be careful with this C-style approach; it is not all that usual in Perl to directly change caller's data. If you only need to fill a hash in the sub then build it there and `return \%hash;`

Comment: That. Or return a hashref in the first place.

Comment: It seems artificial to create a reference only to dereference it... If that's the only way then so be it. I wonder what the overhead could be.

Comment: @Georg Well, I agree.  But your sub returns a flat list, while you don't want to create another hash, to avoid later copying. So then you need a reference, but then you need a value from the structure as well.  The solution is to return a hashref to start with.  Other than being "better" this may actually save a data copy, since the function returns the pointer while the way you have it it returns the whole list.  I say "may" since I am not entirely sure whether there are some optimizations in place, but I don't think that there can be.

Comment: @Georg I added a comment on returning by reference.