# What is the meaning of this line keys(%S)=@C_fields;?

Tags: perl, hash

I have one general question in Perl.What is the meaning of below line

```
keys(%S)=@C_fields;
```

Comment: the line seems to be a junk. you are extracting values on both LHS and RHS which has no meaning.

Comment: Not completely - calling `keys` in a void context does do _something_ but I very much doubt it's what the original coder intended.

Answer (score 8):

`keys(%S)=@C_fields;` is identical to `keys(%S) = scalar @C_fields;`

and from [`perldoc -f keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)

> Used as an lvalue, keys allows you to **increase the number of hash buckets allocated for the given hash**. This can gain you a measure of efficiency if you know the hash is going to get big. (This is similar to pre-extending an array by assigning a larger number to $#array.) If you say
>
> `keys %hash = 200;`
>
> then %hash will have at least 200 buckets allocated for it--256 of them, in fact, since it rounds up to the next power of two.

So hash `%S` will get number of buckets which are at least size of `@C_fields` array.

Comment: More on keys/bucket topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723172/what-is-4-16-in-hashes

Comment: [This article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/) comes to mind, particularly the final point.

Comment: @RobEarl you mean, to explain above why one would like to manually assign number of buckets in the first place?

Comment: No, to tell other programmers that's what the code is doing

Comment: @Сухой27 if you just create a hash a default number of buckets are allocated. If you assign values into it, it may eventually need to allocate more buckets, at which point every key will need to be rehashed across the new set of buckets. If you keep adding keys this may happen again. Also, I *think* when bucket allocation is increased it is always doubled, which might waste memory. Having said that, the pre-allocation of buckets is not commonly used and is likely to be a premature optimisation

Comment: @GrantMcLean also, it is unclear what big means in `This can gain you a measure of efficiency if you know the hash is going to get big. `